# How to play songs in java web application and to make download link

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to test small web application with jee.In this application I want to add
some songs files which can run on line and can be downloaded.But I start just studying now
and I don't know how to make to play songs  in jsp or jsf and I also don't know to make links which can download songs files . Please help and teach me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The downloading of songs is pretty easy.  Just make a link to the file on your server and, because of that files MIME type, your browser will automatically know what do with it.  For example, if you want provide a download for mp3:

```
<a href='mySong.mp3'>Download Now</a>
```

That would generate a download for the music file.

As for streaming music, well that's a bit tougher.  There are different approaches for this, some involving Javascript or Flash.  If you want to try some bleeding edge HTML 5 stuff, there is a very cool approach. This works in Google Chrome, and possibly Firefox too (i havent tested that).

```
<audio src="horse.ogg" controls="controls">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This allows you to embed your audio right in the web page without any Javascript.